# Dynamic PDF with html-pdf npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, node-html-pdf

When creating a Dynamic PDF in node using html-pdf, the content became cut at the end of pages.

[image: Image of PDF]

In html, added `<div id="pageFooter"></div>`

Code that used to create PDF is

```
   pdf.create(finalstr, {
          format: "A3",
          "footer": {
            "height": "10mm",
          }
    })
```

Is there any solution?

Is it possible to create PDF from HTML using PhantomJs?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pdf.create(finalstr, {
  format: "A3",
  "footer": {
    "height": "10mm",
  },
  "border": {
    "bottom": "10mm"
  }
})
```

Comment: Added. The height of footer is increased. Still cutting the characters.

Comment: Please describe the solution with a little detail.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, you can change height of header and footer..**

`pdf.create(finalstr, {
  format: "A4",
 "header": {
    "height": "20mm"
  }
  "footer": {
    "height": "20mm",
  }
})`